# Greasemonkey script fails passing date/time to GM_setValue

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script where I want to know when it was last run. To do this, I wanted to store the current time  with `GM_setValue` and compare that time to the  time when the script is run again.

However, it seems that the `Date().getTime()` results won't pass to `GM_setValue`. For instance if you run:

```
var newtime = new Date().getTime();
GM_setValue('lastrun', newtime);
alert(GM_getValue('lastrun'));
```

There's obviously errors since the alert box won't pop up. However if you replace the first line with:

```
var newtime = 1;
```

you then get 1 returned in the alert box like you would expect.

That pretty much just isolates the date format causing the issue here. Any ideas on how to deal with this, or better ways to save dates between times a script has run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  The number is too large to be stored as a firefox cookie value. My solution was to limit the precision to the second (divide by 1000, drop remainder) and subtract 43 years (1356998400 seconds) to bring the date measured from to Midnight Jan 1st 2013 so my code looks like this:

```
var time = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 1356998400);
GM_setValue("runTime", time);
```

and the retrieval looked like:

```
   var time = GM_getValue("runTime", 0);
        if (time != 0) {
        var cur = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 1356998400);
        var cur = cur - time;
        var sec = cur % 60;
        var min = Math.floor(cur / 60);
        console.log("Script took " + min + ":" + sec);
        }
```

Comment: you could also convert back into a date object with:  
var lastrun = new Date((GM_getValue("runTime")+1356998400)*1000);